# Question about Derivative and Slope at a Point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What does $dy/dx = 2x$ mean?
It means the slope or "rate of change" at any point is $2x$.

So when $x=2$ the slope is $2x = 4$, as shown here:

Or when $x=5$ the slope is $2x = 10$, and so on.

But what does it mean if $dy/dx = 2x/y$?

Does it mean that now

when $x = 2$ we have to put the corresponding value of $y$ for $x = 2$ also to get $dy/dx$

for example if $x = 2$ and suppose $y = 4$ for $x = 2$ then according to the equation $dy/dx = 2(2)/4 = 1$

so slope at point $x = 2$ is now $1$?

Am I right in this assumption ?

Comment: Yes. Your assumption is right.